# Western Digital 500Gb My Book external harddrive won't start

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive, power-supply

I have a Western Digital External Hard drive My Book 500Gb USB2.0

I accidentally put in my laptop power adapter (19V) instead of the Western Digital adapter (12V) so I most likely have fried my power board. I know I can remove the hard drive and put in into a PC, but I only have a laptop.  So, I'd really love to repair it.

If the power inverter board has failed - how do I replace it? I have searched for the part number (`p/n 4060-705002-001rev.a`) but haven't found it.

(P.S. Also it would be good if the new designs had a unique shaped power plug on the WD adapter to prevent this sort of thing happening)

Comment: As others have suggested, buy a new hard drive enclosure, remove the drive from the old enclosure and put it in the new one.

Answer (score 1):

you can buy hard drive cases as well. They are pretty cheap ($20-50) and you probably can do this yourself.

Comment: Yeah good idea - but have never seen them... I will need to ask around.

Comment: There's a few on ebay (http://shop.ebay.com.au/i.html?_nkw=hard+drive+enclosure&_sacat=0&_dmpt=LH_DefaultDomain_15&_odkw=hard+drive+casing&_osacat=0&_trksid=p3286.c0.m270.l1313), but I don't know the size of your hard drive